FX Option, USDCNY smile surface, delta extrap from 10RR,25RR,ATM,25BF,10BF
I am reading the Uwe' paper, FX Volatility Smile Construction, and try to do the delta exptra with formula below but no lucky.
I am using Malz formula here, https://quantpie.co.uk/fx/fx_smile_malz.php  and get market data as 10RR,25RR,ATM,25BF,10BF then try to build the surface like 10DPUT 15DPUT  25DPUT  35DPUT  ATM 35DCAL  25DCAL  15DCAL  10DCAL  5DCAL.
sorry for no lucky to upload pictures, I compared my calculation with BBG and reuter eikon, neither matched.
so any papers should I read further?
Many thanks.

BBG doesn't use Malz, and I would be surprised anyone does. Ask the help desk for a white paper about OVDV and read the help page for the methodology BBG uses.
